# Double overflow

Tags: c#, .net

I have some problems with double type.
At MSDN i read about [double max value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.double.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) following:

> The result of an operation that exceeds Double.MaxValue is Double.PositiveInfinity.

I wrote some tests:

```
Console.WriteLine(double.MaxValue + 100000 - double.MaxValue);
Console.WriteLine(double.MaxValue);
Console.WriteLine(double.MaxValue + 100000);
Console.WriteLine(double.IsPositiveInfinity(double.MaxValue + 100000));
```

And saw this result:

```
0
1,79769313486232E+308
1,79769313486232E+308
False
```

I don't understand, double.MaxValue + 100000 isn't Positive infinity, but equal to double MaxValue. I think it should be PositiveInfinity, according to msdn documentation.

I tested it in VS2012, .NET 4.5

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is rounding / precision; from the perspective of a number that is 309 digits long (before the decimal place), `100000` is essentially zero. You might as well add `0`.

If you try `double.MaxValue * 2` - i.e. something that will actually be noticeable to it, then it will show as positive infinity.

Comment: interesting, so basically its not mathematically correct with doubles?

Comment: @ServéLaurijssen of course it isn't mathematically correct; `double`, `float` and `decimal` are all approximations (although `double`/`float` take a different approach to representing that approximation than does `decimal`). If you take a **really large** number and make a **really small** change to it, it is perfectly expected for that to be completely lost due to precision. Ultimately, `double` needs to store a huge variety of numbers in 8 bytes; there are only so many ways of doing that, and only so many numbers that can be expressed. Can you store `Math.PI` in 8 bytes?

Comment: @ServéLaurijssen there is interesting [article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) on this theme

Comment: @ServéLaurijssen I've also written an article in the past about the topic of doubles, floats and decimals. You might want to check it out ([link](http://luaan.cz/articles/ckrizek/decimal-trouble/))

Answer (score 10):

`Double` only has about 15 decimal digits of precision thus when you add `Double.MaxValue` to `100000D` there is no overflow because the `1` in `100000D` has to be added after the 300th digit of `Double.MaxValue` and this is the same as adding 0.

If you perform the following calculation

```
Double.MaxValue + Double.MaxValue/1e16
```

you do get positive infinity.

Comment: as far as I can remember, double inf is def. as 1/0. But don't ask me why there is no DivideByZeroException.

Comment: @thefiloe `double`/`float` don't throw divide-by-zero, overflow, etc; integers do that